# Ensure pipeline always results in array without using @()?

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline

Is there any nice way to ensure a pipeline result is always an array without the array literal `@()`?

Currently, I always found myself writing pipeline and assume that the result is an array, e.g.

```
$Results = $ResultFiles | Where Name -like $Pattern | Sort -Unique Name

# Processing that assume $Results is array, e.g.
Out-Host -InputObject "found $($Results.Length) matching files..."

# Further processing that assume $Results is array
```

Then, I realize that I need to ensure `$Results` is always an array. So, I come back to add the magic `@()`, `@(` in front and `)` at the back:

```
$Results = @( <pipeline_statement> )
```

or even more magic by adding to an empty array

```
$Results = @() + <pipeline_statement>
```

My question: is there any way to ensure that a pipeline always results in an array? that doesn't requires the "magic" `@()`? I think of creating a function to collect pipeline results, e.g. `ConvertTo-Array`, like:

```
$Results = <pipeline_statement> | ConvertTo-Array
```

But I'd rather use default Cmdlet or idioms if any.

**Note**:
I also tempted to create `ConvertTo-CustomObject` as I often found myself creating `PSCustomObject` from hash table.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. There is an ability to directly typecast a single value to an array. If that value is already a `[Object[]]` nothing is effectively changed.

```
[Array]$result=<pipeline_statement>
```

As mentioned in comments by @wannabeprogrammer, this does not convert null value into an array. If something can return null, the following addition will remedy the situation:

```
if ($result -eq $null) { $result = @() }
```

Comment: Hmm... that's a nice way, with caveat that it will generate `$null` instead of zero length array if the pipeline results in zero object.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer Well, if I do `[array]$a=$null; $a.length` I get 0. So, if needed, one can check length prior to running any foreach code. `$a | foreach { "b" }` results in one iteration with null supplied as `$_`. Still, if one is aware that something can return null, they can write `if ($a -eq $null) { $a=@() }`